# any log search system can help build index locally and grep log in a centralized node?

Tags: elastic-stack

I read the ELK document and other log grep system,seems all of them need to:

1. send the logs to a centralized server
2. centralized server build index

I think those ELK like system cost too much disk and bandwidth.Any implementation works like distributed grep with index？
Log files are distributed in many servers. Log system are implemented on each servers also. centralized server request to each servers for getting the result of grep applied to log data,with the help of index built,this task can be fast,and results are collected to centralized server.

Answer (score 0):

The use case for parsing logs with UNIX powertools (sed, grep, awk etc.) is an age old use case and not really a very efficient one. It also becomes a maintenance nightmare once you change something in your scripts and want to apply it throughout the servers.

Finding patterns across multiple type of log files across multiple applications is challenging and understanding/creating the regular expressions for each is not very easy.

ELK provides good tools for parsing - read up on logstash. It has a fantastic grok filter, wide range of input/output plugins.

From disk usage, infact it would be easier to maintain Elasticsearch data, as you can selective drop indices based on hour/day/month basis (really depends on how you created the index). If your logfile is 10GB for whatever reason with a 6 month old data, and you want to clean it up to keep only last month data, depending upon type of logs, it will be difficult to do that.